# How to modify the format of all the values in particular column in Perl array?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, multidimensional-array, dbi

I was reading each row from a result set (multi-dimensional array, as rows and columns are dynamic) and modifying the format for all date fields at specific positions in the array. But this is taking much time as the result set is returning more rows.

Below is sample code which i have used to change row level , is there any possibility to change whole column values in array with regexp? Or any other way to improve this program ?

```perl
$sth = $dbh->prepare( "BEGIN TESTPROC(?, ?, ?); END;" );

$sth->bind_param( 1, 'GMS_JOB_NAME' );
$sth->bind_param_inout( 5, \$ResultSet, 0, { ora_type => ORA_RSET } );
$sth->bind_param_inout( 6, \$out_date, VARCHAR2 );

unless ( $sth->execute() ) {
    print "Couldnt be invoked";
}

my $temp_file = "/user/test.csv";
my $i         = 0;
my $flag      = 0;

my @type;
my @precision;
my @date_type;

if ( $flag == 0 ) {

    $j = 0;

    while ( $i < $num_fields ) {

        $type[$i]      = $ResultSet->{TYPE}->[$i];
        $precision[$i] = $ResultSet->{PRECISION}->[$i];

        if ( $type[$i] == 93 and $precision[$i] == 75 ) {
            $date_type[$j] = $i;
            $j = $j + 1;
        }

        $i = $i + 1;
    }

    $flag = 1;
}

$i = 0;

if ( $out_date ) {

    unless ( open( FH, '>>', "$temp_file" ) ) {
        print "Unable to open the Report file $temp_file";
    }

    $file_check = 1;
    my $num_fields = $ResultSet->{NUM_OF_FIELDS};

    while ( @record = $ResultSet->fetchrow_array ) {

        $record_flag = 1;

        foreach $k ( @date_type ) {

            if ( defined $record[$k] ) {

                my $pos = rindex( $record[$k], "." );

                $record[$k] =~ s/\./:/g;

                if ( $pos ne -1 ) {
                    substr( $record[$k], $pos, 1 ) = ".";
                }

                my $dt = `date -d"$record[$k]" +"%d-%b-%Y"`;
                chomp( $dt );

                $dt = uc $dt;

                $record[$k] = $dt;
            }

        }

        if ( index( $record[0], "\"" ) eq -1 ) {
            my $data = join( '","', @record );
            $data = '"' . $data . '"';
        }
    }


$dbh->commit();
$sth->finish();
$ResultSet->finish();
```

Below is the sample data with 10 columns and 7 rows. this would be retrieved into array `$ResultSet` from the database with space as delimiter.

The result set is not limited to this number of rows and columns; it could be in thousands of columns with millions of rows.

From the data below I want to change the format of dates for all values in  columns 3, 4, and 5 in the result set. The current approach is doing it row by row and writing it into CSV file, but this is slow.

Is there any better option to do this?

```
    1 A 2014/09/09 2014/09/09 2014/09/09 AMETIC NONRRA 1 122121 1212.432
    2 b 2014/09/09 2014/01/09 2014/09/09 AMETIC NONRRA 1 122121 1212.432
    3 B 2014/09/09 2014/04/09 2014/09/09 AMETIC NONRRA 1 122121 1212.432
    4 R 2014/09/09 2014/05/09 2014/09/09 AMETIC NONRRA 1 122121 1212.432
    5 G 2014/09/09 2014/07/09 2016/09/09 AMETIC NONRRA 1 122121 1212.432
    6 DD 2014/09/09 2015/03/09 2014/09/09 AMETIC NONRRA 1 122121 1212.432
    7 DSSS 2014/09/09 2015/09/06 2015/09/09 AMETIC NONRRA 1 122121 1212.432
```

Comment: Is this a CSV file you are parsing? If so `Text::CSV` may be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the comment Varlogtim. I was trying to write the result set data from Oracle db to csv file.

Comment: I don't understand this. What is the problem -- is it too slow? Can you describe what you are trying to do with data, and can you show us some of the data you are processing (after you pull it out of the database)?

Comment: If the date fields are stored as dates in your database (and not just as strings) then you can choose the output format that you get when you fetch the data. It would be better to do that than to alter the result afterwards. What is the bit about changing all but the last dot `.` to colons `:`?

Comment: @zdim you are right about point 2. That is typo , @date_type is array of positions to be modified for date fields and it should be global for whole script. I want to modify the format of date to **`date -d"$record[$k]" +"%d-%b-%Y"`**  . For now I was going row by row to do this but which is taking much time and I want to know better way of doing this change.

Comment: Thanks @zdim. Couldnt do changes in procedure and this result has to be printed in reports.

Comment: My simple answer is meant to put forth some code so we can clarify what (more) can be done that fits your overall need. It does answer the direct question to reformat the dates and will speed it up some (as it drops the expensive call to the system) but it's not meant to be definitive. In particular, if you can explain what the rest of the code in `foreach $k (@date_type)` does (so I don't have to guess from code) we can probably get rid of that explicit loop altogether.  If you comment I can adjust and/or expand.

Comment: @Devoloper250  Can you comment on how this went?  I'd like to remove the answer if it's of no use.